# Как обнулить цифры идущие после запятой?

Tags: java, float, double

Предположим у нас результатом деления оказалось число типа 2.777777777...( и так до самого конца) сохраненное в double или float.
Можно ли каким то способом обнулить значение после .n.
Пример нам надо .3;
Результат 2.7770000000000000000000000000000000000000 ....
Без какова либо округления, просто как то обнулить биты или что то подобное?

Comment: Советую прочитать, как именно представляются числа в двоичном виде числа с плавающей точкой. `2.777` в двоичном виде - это бесконечная дробь, так что его невозможно точно представить как `float` или `double`. Получите что-то типа `2.77700000000457076...` (несколько нулей, а потом много (хотя конечное число) разрядов мусора).

Comment: Вы хотите округления в *десятичной* дроби. Компьютер же хранит всё в *двоичной* дроби. Два не кратно десяти, а потому точных десятичных дробей вы не получите почти никогда. Из-за этого вам надо не само число округлять, а ограничивать число цифр при печати в человекочитаемом виде.

Comment: Это будет выглядеть как-то так: `System.out.printf("%.3f0000000000000000000000000000000000000", val);` (если вам нужен хвост из нулей) или `System.out.printf("%.3f", val);` (если хвост не нужен).

Comment: @Arhad оно округлит и в итоге 2.778 будет, если брать 2.77777...

Comment: Видимо, вся рота идет не в ногу, потому что в вопросе ничего не говорится о форматировании числа в строку ).

Comment: @Igor А для чего надо настолько точно и ровно округлять число, как не для вывода?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double d = 2.777777777777777777777777777777777777777777;
double k = ((int) (d * 1000)) / 1000.0;
System.out.printf("%.100f", k);
```

Напечатает: 2.7770000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так

```
((int)2.777777777*1000)/1000.
```

то есть вы берете флоут или дабл и двигаете запятую или точку вправо на нужное количество символов, а потом возвращаете обратно потеряв при этом дробную чаcть.

---

Можно как-то это разобрать, а то и в прямь 2 печатает

```
double d = 2.777777777*1000; //двигаем вправо
d = (int)d; //отбрасываем дробную часть
d = d/1000; //возвращаем значимую часть
System.out.println(d+"0000000000000000000000000000000000000 ....");
```

Comment: И прямо одни нули будут? Это точно? Мне надо точно знать.

Comment: @igor можете проверить, если там не будет нулей то удалю

Comment: Вот, прошу: [тык](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46b530ba69eaa9f1). Это правда С++, а не джава, но суть должна быть та же. Выставил точность повыше и получил вывод `2.77700000000000013500311979441903531551361083984375`. Что, пора удалять? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(2.777777777777777);
double value = bigDecimal.setScale(3, RoundingMode.DOWN).doubleValue();
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Разве в вопросе что-то говорится о `System.out.println`?

Comment: @Igor какая разница ? Это для наглядности. Чтобы можно было cut and paste и проверить.