# javascript арифметические действия с нужной точностью

Tags: javascript

Интересует вопрос, есть ли в javascript аналогичные библиотеки, как в PHP (например `BCMATH`) для проведения арифметических операций с нужной точностью?

P.s. Из `0.2` вычитаю `0.01808` и получаю `0.18192000000000003`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881067

Comment: Я так понял, все понимают о чем идет речь, а я вот нет). А что значит "с нужной точностью"? Какой результат Вам нужен при отнимании от `0.2` `0.01808`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом toFixed,насчет библиотеки не знаю,но можно написать функцию и указать параметром точность.

```js
const result = 0.2 - 0.01808;
console.log(+result.toFixed(5))
```

Comment: toFixed занимается *уменьшением* точности. Число, выглядящее «круглым», совсем не обязательно является точным https://xkcd.ru/217/ Вдруг автору нужна точность до сотни знаков?

Comment: @andreymal До сотни знаков?))Я думаю Number уже не хватит,разве что https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint